# multi links between Fact_Table & Date_Dimension

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence, dimensional-modeling, star-schema, fact-table

In my Fact_Table I have several Date fields such as:

- order_date
- payment_date
- purchasing_date
- estimated_delivery_date
- actual_delivery_date
- ...

How to choose which ones that need to be linked to the Date_Dimension and the others?

Thank you for your advice,

Comment: All of them should point to the date dimension that becomes a role-playing dimension http://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2011/11/role-playing-dimensions/. What problem are you facing exactly?

Comment: Hi @MarekGrzenkowicz, I don't really have a problem, I was just wondering if it is correct to have like 7 foreign keys from the Date_Dimension into the  Fact_Table. According to what you said and the website you provide it seems so. Thank you then! Have a great day.

Comment: technically, what I would do, is use the same time dimension table and logically use it as orderdatedim, purchdatedim, actualdeliverydatetim etc. its possible in SSAS.

Comment: All right, both of you convince me to do so. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use foreign keys in a data warehouse, as your ETL should take care of integrity. Also, you might want hot-swappable dimensions in the future, and they don't use foreign keys.

Usually, a "smart" key is a bad idea, though I make an exception for dates, as it makes it easy to partition fact tables by date. Use an int type, and values like 20160201 (for Feb 1 2016).

You can, of course, join tables in SQL without foreign keys.